# Using speech-to-text in text messages

Tags: sms, voice-recognition

I've got an Android P690. When I go to compose text in a text message I would like to input it via the microphone by using Google's networked speech recognition engine. However when I hold down the search hardware button and speak, and finish speaking, Android opens up a web browser and performs a web search with the spoken text instead of inserting the text in the SMS text box. And when I press the back button the text I spoke is not in the text box either. So my question is, how do I use the microphone to compose an SMS's body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, now I see the small microphone icon and globe icon for setting the speech language (keeping the globe pressed allows you to choose which languages to toggle back and forth between) on the soft keyboard that comes up.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, accept your own answer (with the little check mark on the left).

Comment: @DanHulme That can be done earliest after 2 days for "your own" answers. But yes, user2239505*, please come back in 2 days and accept. This makes it helpful for other "searchers" to identify questions offering workable solutions.